# Static URL in cherrypy

Tags: python, url, cherrypy

I have a website server based on python (cherrypy), and i need some help. I'm sorry in advance if this question is too basic. I don't have a vast of experience in this area so far.

My main page is on `http://host:9090/home/static/index.html`.
I want to rewrite the address of above, and define the following address as the main page: `http://host:9090/home/`. The code itself suppose to stay in the same place. I just want a shorter link so `/home/static/index.html` will be available also in `/home/`.

Is rewrite URL is what i need? If so, I've found the following link, but unfortunately i don't know how to implement it in my code:
http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2005/10/27/url_rewriting_in_cherrypy_2_1?blog=2

```
 cherrypy.config.update({
                            'server.socket_port': 9090,
                            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'
                           })
    conf = {
        '/': {
                'tools.sessions.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
             },
        '/static': {
                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': './static/html'
             },
        '/js': {
                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': './static/js'
             },
        '/css': {
                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': './static/css'
             },
        '/img': {
                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': './static/img'
             },
        '/fonts': {
                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': './static/fonts'
        }

    }

    class Root(object):
        def __init__(self, target):
            self.target_server = target

    webapp = Root(args.target)
    cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/home', conf)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: @qarma As i mentioned above, i need rewrite URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my projects, I usually point `'/'` directly to the static folder. I prefer to omit all appearances of `'static'` in my URLs, and imho it's a good practice to serve a resource only through exactly one URL. Anyway, it  could be a simple solution to manually write the mapping, if the same static resource has to be served through different URLs.

For example, the folder structure looks as follows:

```
repo \
    __init__.py
    main.py
    static \
        test \
            some-module.js
```

It's handy to have the path to the root directory as a global variable, here I call it `SITE_ROOT`.

```
SITE_ROOT = '/home/user/repo'
conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
    },
    '/test': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'test'
    },
    '/static/test': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'test'
    },
}
```

Now both URLs lead to the same static resource, without redirection.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/some-module.js
http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/test/some-module.js
```

Further reading:

https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/progguide/files/static.html#forming-urls